# quickfix stunnel config connect

Tags: python, quickfix, stunnel

I am trying to create a program through Python using the quick fix library that needs to connect to the server a fixed ip and connect to stunnel. I have a static ip from the resource in the stunnel configuration file and put this code [gmail-smtp]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:25
connect = 125.236.36. But when creating the self-certificate in comon name i.e. the IP I put is 127.0.0.1 or the fixed IP knowing that the fixed IP is connected to the connector so the IP that appears after the ipconfig command is the IP of the modem I put the IP of the modem did not accept the certificate as well as the fixed IP as well It did not work, the server did not accept the certificate, knowing that the server accepts the self-certificate, but when writing one of these IPs in the certificate, an error appears CN=localhost
2023.06.14 14:08:28 LOG3[6]: SSL_connect: ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1889: error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed What is the solution? When the certificate is revoked, it connects to the server, but does not log in

thank you for help me